# Does SharePoint Designer only use jpeg images and not tif images?

Tags: website-design

I uploaded a tif image into SharePoint Designer but it will not display on the web page.  Does it have to be jpeg? I have uploaded jpeg images and they work fine but I erased a background on an image and saved it as a tif.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might work for some browsers and not for others, but it's also possible that Sharepoint is rejecting it outright.  I'd recommend sticking to any of the standard web formats: JPEG, GIF, and sometimes PNG.

TIFFs are uncompressed, so they're really large and as such not very web-friendly. They're handy as a backup format though, should you ever need to make changes to the site later.

Comment: **Sometimes** PNG? Why only sometimes? PNG support is excellent among browsers these days and the format beats GIF and JPEG on technical merits for many (although not all, GIF and JPEG are still better for some things) types of image.

Comment: TIFF has supported compression since version 5 of the specification came out … in 1988.

Comment: I put "sometimes" because IE6 still exists. And while TIFFs technically can be compressed, most impls were weak or non-standard. "Caution should be exercised when using TIFFs", etc: http://www.aiim.org/article.aspx?ID=36656  It's practical use is for scanners & OCR now, hence "uncompressed."

Comment: IE6 has a problem only with translucency in PNG images … which JPEG, GIF and TIFF don't support anyway.